# ApexCharts bubble - Change quarter background color

Tags: apexcharts

I am using ng-apexcharts, and I want to change only quarter of the background to another color like in the following example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZrPR.png)

Currently using annotations with offestY, but we cant understand what is the offestY value and how we can make it 50% of the graph size.

Code example:

```
chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        height: auto,
        ...
      },
      annotations: {
        xaxis: [
          {
            x: 50,
            x2: 100,
            fillColor: '#f15252',
            opacity: 0.1,
            offsetY: -70, // How to calculate this value to be exactly 50% offest?
          }
        ],
      },
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, maybe it will help someone:

```
        events: {
          mounted: (chart, options) => {
            const offsetX = options.globals.gridWidth / 2;
            this.chart.addYaxisAnnotation({
              y: 5,
              y2: 10,
              fillColor: '#f15252',
              opacity: 0.1,
              offsetX,
            });
          },
        }
```